# React Native App slows down as usage time increases

Tags: react-native

React Native App slows down as usage time increases.

The speed is fine the first time my app is launched.
However, as time passes, the app becomes slower and slower.
Is there any way to track this down?

ex) `TextInput` input speed is slow.

Comment: what are you using for navigation? react-navigation? and how do you switch to different screens? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') or this.props.navigation.push('Home') ?

Comment: @GauravRoy using react-navigation and this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')

Comment: what i can suggest is you try your profiler option in xcode and see what is taking up memory utilization